# Error Installing MySQL From Source on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL from source as part of a uni project - something I have never done before - and am getting the following error message when trying to `make`:

```
[ 79%] Building CXX object sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/mysqld.cc.o
/home/me/mysql-5.5.17/sql/mysqld.cc: In function ‘void handle_connections_sockets()’:
/home/me/mysql-5.5.17/sql/mysqld.cc:5270:31: error: invalid conversion from ‘size_socket* {aka int*}’ to ‘socklen_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:214:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int accept(int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)’ [-fpermissive]
/home/me/mysql-5.5.17/sql/mysqld.cc:5337:48: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘socklen_t* {aka unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/socket.h:119:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int getsockname(int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)’ [-fpermissive]
make[2]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/mysqld.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sql/CMakeFiles/sql.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have absolutely no idea how I can fix this as it seems to be a problem with the C++ code itself. Does anyone more knowledgeable have a solution?

**EDIT:** I am installing mySQL 5.5.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this bug report seems to be related to your problem](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37582) and includes [a patch that may correct the error you have](http://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=9550)

Answer (score 0):

I do the following in order to overcome such problems in building the source code of a package:

1. Check the configure script output carefully. You may got some important warnings and you did not notice them. Sometimes, you may be missing some package(s).
2. Try to clean your build before building again using `make clean` or `make distclean`.
3. If that did not work, you can also try a different version of the package to eliminate the option of a recent bug.